# How to use ajax to upload excel and return pptx(python-django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, powerpoint

I am trying to use django,python-pptx to upload a excel and return ppt. I am alredy successful in using ajax to upload excel as well as using python-pptx to make ppt.But I fail in how to return ppt file and how to download it(i want to use ajax mthod).
There are two main problems that I can't solve

first,I can't use ajax to make a form, because the csrf always stop me.I know `formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}')`
but I can't use it in

```
if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) { 
                                var form = $('<form action="' + '/auto/' + '" method="post"></form>');
                                $('body').append(form);`enter code here
<script>
    function loadFile(file) {
        $("#filename").html(file.name);
        console.log(file.name)
    }
    $("#btn").bind("click", function() {

                var formdata = new FormData()
                var file = $("#ranran")[0].files[0]
                formdata.append('file', file)
                formdata.append('name', file['name'])
                formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}')
                console.log(formdata)


                $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "/auto/",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function(response, status, request) {
                            var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                            if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) { 
                                var form = $('<form action="' + '/auto/' + '" method="post"></form>');
                                $('body').append(form);
                                form.submit();
                            }

                        }
                })
            })
</script>`
```

second, how can I return the fileReponse

```
from pptx import Presentation
from django.http import FileResponse
prs = Presentation()
return FileResponse(prs)
```

it says
'Presentation' object is not iterable

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Probably need to save the presentation as a file or `io.BytesIO` before applying `FileResponse()`. Something like prs.save("my-prs.pptx"). Search on saving to an in-memory file if you don't want the file system getting littered with download temporary files.